# Equivalent of Arduino's yield(), delay() for ESP8266 with SMING framework

Tags: arduino, esp8266, sming

I am using SMING framework for ESP8266

yield(), delay() is used by ESP8266 Arduino to move processing to the CPU. THis reduces random resets when certain processes take too long. Does the SMING framework have equivalent functions for yield() and delay()?

Answer (score 0):

yield function which is equivalent with delay(0), is used for getting rid of WDT resets to give process priority to cpu time. So as SMING is also on RTOS, better to switch to it and forget all about them.